# What are the cooldowns for the Divine Beasts' Abilities?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Each beast gives you an ability. But that ability can only be used every once in a while.

What is the cooldown on these abilities?

Also, I've seen my SO play, and some have x1, x2 next to it. Are those stacks? and if yes, how much can you get per ability?

Comment: If you scroll over to your key items in your inventory and look at each blessing it tells you the cooldown in game-time once the ability is in cooldown (i.e. use all charges of an ability).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The numbers are indeed stacks. The ability will not start restoring until all stacks are used.

- Zora ability is 1x (with a cooldown of 24 minutes)
- Gerudo ability is 3x (with a cooldown of 12 minutes)
- Rito ability is 3x (with a cooldown of 6 minutes)
- Goron ability is 3x (with a cooldown of 18 minutes)

Comment: I am pretty certain that the Zora ability has 30 ingame minutes cooldown. Don't have the other ones yet, though.

Comment: Worth adding that the abilities will not start to restore until all charges are used. So if you have 1 charge of an ability, it will not restore to 3 charges until you use that 1 charge up.

Comment: I've updated the answer to account for those tidbits.

Comment: I believe the Zora ability is ~20 minutes, and I believe the Gerudo one is ~12. No hard numbers today, unfortunately.

Comment: I have confirmed that Mipha's Grace is 24 minutes after activation.

Comment: Daruk's Protection is 18 minutes after the 3rd activation.

Comment: Urbosa's Fury (Gerudo) takes 12 minutes to recharge after the last charge has been used. You can see how much time is remaining by looking at the key items in your inventory (I don't yet have the other abilities to check their cooldowns)

Comment: @3Doubloons Thanks! Didn't know that.

Comment: Rito is shortest, I think it's something like 7 minutes

Answer (score 6):

There seems to be a little confusion on this in the other answer, even though it was accepted already. Here it shows the names of the abilities.

- Rivali's Gale - 6 minutes
- Urbosa's Fury - 12 minutes
- Daruk's Protection - 18 minutes
- Mipha's Grace - 24 minutes

Note that all except Mipha's Grace have 3 uses before the cooldown comes into effect.

These times correspond to the day-night cycle of the game.  The game's clock runs one minute for each second in real-world time, so the game has a 24 minute day-night cycle.  Each of the powers correspond to 1/4, 1/2, 3/4, and 1 full day to recharge.  Fast forwarding by sitting by a fire or sleeping in a bed does not speed this along.

Update for how the Champion's Ballad DLC changed things

> The DLC will allow you to unlock story missions related to each of the divine beasts. The completion of each Champion's quest will cause their power to decrease to 1/3 the original time, so the new cooldown times are:
>  Rivali's Gale - 2 minutes,
>  Urbosa's Fury - 4 minutes,
>  Daruk's Protection - 6 minutes,
>  Mipha's Grace - 8 minutes

Comment: Are the cooldowns decreased *to* 1/3 or decreased  *by* 1/3? I haven't done the DLC yet, but also couldn't find a reference mentioning the reduced cooldowns either. Decreasing to 1/3 seems a little OP

Comment: @Wondercricket decreased to 1/3. I beat the DLC two days ago and can confirm the times I listed above. It is really OP, boss fights are so much easier when you can expect the power to recharge during the time you are fighting them.